# Keyboard layout for programming fr-ca user

Tags: keyboard, typing, keyboard-layout, ergonomics

I already know this has been asked countless times, but here is the problem.

I am thinking about making my typing speed up and right now the pick and hunt method that I badly gained using qwerty has made me a slow typist (qwerty makes me fell clumsy). I am using a laptop and I'm not afraid to learn a new layout.

I have been looking at Dvorak for a while but i am not convinced yet because I need a layout that I can use for **both writing and codding with access to accents** eg: êèé and ç
because I am french Canadian.

As far as I can see these are hard to meet, still I could be wrong.

Thank you all, have an amazing day.

Comment: Why change from qwerty? You could try the us-international layout (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#US-International). The use of dead keys can be problematic while programming, but switching the layout with a shortcut depending on the task could be a workaround. Alternative: create a new layout based on QWERTY-US, adding whatever characters you need using "AltGr" (or Alt+Ctrl).

Comment: I found a varient of dvorak that has the caracters I need ... problem is I still sometimes need to use windows machines that has no support of that particular dvorak varient meaning .... I still need to relearn querty in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [EurKEY](https://eurkey.steffen.bruentjen.eu/). It is based on the US standard layout, which is best for programming and you have access to é, à, è, ù, ë, ï, ö, ÿ, ç, œ and æ and all capital counterparts. The circonflex letters, â î ô û, however are a bit difficult to reach. The keyboard is available for Windows and MAC OS X, and it's already included in many Linux distros. All free.

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend Eurkey myself. At work we use qwerty keyboards (still great for coding) but for writing in French, it is a pain in the a**. Have a look at Eurkey, uses the normal querty layout but in addition all special characters are easily accessible using the altGR key.

Answer (score 0):

I personally built my custom layout using Microsoft keyboard layout creator.
The idea is to use the altgr key to create enable typing new symbols using the home row.
the layout looks like this:

```
no shift:
1234567890)=
azertyuiop=-*
qsdfghjklm_
wxcvbn,;:!

shifted:
&é"45-è_çà)+
AZERTYUIOP+$/
QSDFGHJKLM%
WXCVBN?./§

altgr + a: "
altgr + z: '
altgr + e: {
altgr + r: }
altgr + q: <
altgr + s: >
altgr + d: (
altgr + f: )
altgr + w: |
altgr + x: &
altgr + c: [
altgr + v: ]
```

Most of the symbols used for programming are available without moving your hands too much.
Also, there are a few duplicates, if that bothers you just put something else instead. I chose to keep the duplicates because it minimizes the pain for everybody else who might need to type something on my keyboard.